# CPUutilization of a micro instance on Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, rds

I am a bit confused by the data shown by CloudWatch for a micro instance. Because a micro instance can use up to two CPU instances for a short period of time, is the cpuutilization shown in Cloudwatch for one CPU or two? For example, if I see Cloudwatch showing my micro instance cpuutilization is 100% for a short period of time, does it mean that it is using two CPUs and both CPUs are 100% or it is showing just one CPU which is at 100%?

Comment: Any updates on how your services have been running with whatever solution you went with? Care to share them with me? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have always understood the utilization metric to indicate percent usage on ALL cores across your instances. This percentage is a reflection of total usage versus maximum capacity in your instance class, which for you is micro.

Because micro is the free tier, you can expect throttling to kick in quite fast on any micro instance, so don't utilize it much for any hard work (if at all). If you're going to see regular 100% usage on your micro instance, it would benefit you to upgrade to a small instance at least so that throttling doesn't annihilate your services when your spike lasts a second too long.

I've been using micro for a year or so now, and I definitely advise against using the free/micro tier for any kind of heavy lifting. A "few" spikes to 100% utilization is fine, but it sounds like this is more regular than a once-in-a-while kind of thing for you.

Comment: Thanks! I am running some testing with a micro version of RDS rather than a EC2, but I think they both work the same way. So if I understand you correctly, 100% means that 2 cores are running at 100%. My usage pattern is kind interesting, we have a peak period for about 12 hours per day. During peak period, I would see the cpuutilization touching 100% about 25 times, basically 2-3 times per hour. Each time it lasts only 2-3 minutes. If I do an average over the whole 12 hours, it is around 40-50% cpuutilization. Is small instance a better option?

Comment: Yes. And there's really not much explanation needed beyond the simple fact that -- like any other service on the planet -- you are no longer a free tier user and therefore subject to far fewer restrictions on activity. Currently in the micro instance, it feels like about 10 or 15 minutes is the upper limit on the time your utilization can stay peaked at 100%. Then it just pulls the rug out from underneath you. I personally have a free tier micro, and a small instance for quasi-work-related stuff, and the small really is worth it.

Comment: Also be advised that you could possibly keep your data "frontend" attached to a micro, then tie over-utilization or heavy lifting to a small instance "on demand" (versus reserved instance) in the background on call to save bucks, since reserved instances aren't the cheapest way to get things done. ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for the data points. Regarding the frontend and backend suggestion, since my case is RDS rather than EC2, I think it would be hard to partition. So maybe the easiest is just upgrade to a small instance. What you think? Thanks!

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry. I forgot you were doing that. Of course RDS is a whole different beast in this regard, so yeah, put the whole thing on a small instance. :)

Comment: Because I'm interested to see how your migration and fledgling small RDS instance goes (and in general stuff with AWS), would you mind keeping me updated here when you have an opinion on how it affected your particular situation?